# Eclipse crashed, files got corrupted, now I can't install or uninstall EGit plugin

Tags: windows, eclipse, egit

I am trying to configure Eclipse for Windows to meet my workplace's requirements, and in doing so the program ran out of memory and crashed. I am trying again with a fresh install (deleted all files I could find related to Eclipse and recopied).

I have a Git perspective available, but it is completely blank. Git is not listed in my current plugins, and not present in my plugins folder that I can find. If I try to install it, however, I am told it already exists.

Eclipse Version: 3.6.2

EGit Version: 1.1.0.201109151100-r

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can usually fix a lot of problems like this by doing a

```
$ eclipse -clean
```

You may have to add this to your eclipse.ini file.

If this doesn't work, start from a clean install (the eclipse directory & the workspace).